# Sonar doesn't increment cyclomatic complexity score for 'forEach' loops in java

Tags: java, sonarlint, cyclomatic-complexity

Suppose that I have the following code.

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> { //No Sonar cyclomatic complexity score

  for (String s : value) {   //Sonar lint : +2 (including 1 for nesting) 
    if (condition) {...}     //Sonar lint : +3 (including 2 for nesting)
  }

}
```

As mentioned above for the *for* loop Sonar assign a score of 2, considering both facts of linear structure breaking and nesting altogether. That's perfectly fine.

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> { //No Sonar cyclomatic complexity score

  value.forEach(s-> {        //No Sonar cyclomatic complexity score
    if (condition) {...}     //Sonar lint : +3 (including 2 for nesting)
  }); 

}
```

But if I refactor the *for* loop for a *forEach* loop as above, all the Sonar complaints on cyclomatic complexities for the *for* loop will go away. But as you can see for the *if* statement cyclomatic complexity is the same. That means for the *if* statement Sonar considers the same score (score of 2) for the nesting, implying that it is nested 2 levels below (since it is under two *forEach* statements).

My question is what is the logic behind Sonar not calculating cyclomatic complexity for *forEach* loop in both structural and nesting wise though it has calculated the structural and nested cyclomatic complexities for the *if* statement. Is this correct or some bug in SonarLint plugin?

Answer (score 2):

> The cyclomatic complexity of a method (or constructor) is the number
>   of possible linearly-independent execution paths through that method
>   (see [Wikipedia]). It was originally introduced as a complexity
>   measure by Thomas McCabe [McCabe].

This is not about the for-each vs for-loop, It's just because of the lambda expression, lambda expression makes it an anonymous method invocation hence it is not considered cyclomatic complexity of your method, as it becomes a linear path in your method.